# I want a loop where each time it is called by a function the I value stays the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am attempting to write a dealer function for a card game, I want the function to keep its `i` value each time its called, so that that the card pile( `player1Deck` and `player2Deck`) gets smaller and smaller till empty. currently the `i` value looks like it will reset each time the function is called how can I stop this.
I am very new to all of this.

```
function dealOut(){
    for (let i = 0; i < player1DeckHandcells.length; i++) {
        const cell = player1DeckHandcells[i];
        cell.appendChild(player1Deck.cards[i].getHTML)
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < player2DeckHandcells.length; i++) {
        const cell = player2DeckHandcells[i];
        cell.appendChild(player2Deck.cards[i].getHTML)
    }
}
```

**More information**

Each `dealout` call should make `i` increase by 7. this means we are on the 8th "card"(`player1Deck.cards[i].getHTML` and `player2Deck.cards[i].getHTML`) in the "deck"( `player1Deck` and `player2Deck`)and there should be a total of 28 cards with 21 left to go. I want the `i` value to count through these "cards", so it doesn't just repeat the first 7 every time `dealout` is called.

Comment: Can you also include examples of what `player1Deck` and `player2Deck` should look like before and after a call to `dealOut`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to reduce the `i` value _once_ each time the function is called, not keep it the same.

Comment: @kingkupps I added more information if you're able to help now that would be much appreciated .

Comment: @Andy  I added more information if you're able to help now that would be much appreciated .

Comment: Have you considered using a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)? Imo this would be the proper way to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a closure (a function that keeps a copy of the outer variables). We can use that function for `dealOut`. Note: arrays are zero-indexed so `i` starts at `0` not `1`.

```js
function loop() {

  // Maintain a count
  let count = 0;
  
  // Return a function that we actually use
  // when we call dealOut. This carries a copy
  // of count with it when it's returned that we
  // can update
  return function () {
    
    const arr = [];

    // Set i to count, and increase until
    // i ia count + 7
    for (let i = count; i < count + 7; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    
    console.log(arr.join(' '));
    
    // Finally increase count by 7
    count += 7;
  }
}

const dealOut = loop();

dealOut();
dealOut();
dealOut();
dealOut();
```